# When you drop a feather from high off the ground, when it gets near the ground, how will its speed have changed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, drag

When an object falls, it should fall faster and faster because of gravitational acceleration. But when we are talking about a feather, we have to talk about air resistance. Air resistance is proportional to velocity^2, so what happens? Does the speed increase or decrease or stay the same? Because if the speed is lowered by the air resistance, the air resistance must also be less, if it is proportional to the speed.

Comment: It is called terminal velocity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed will increase and then maximize when the force of gravity equals the drag force. The speed will not increase once this happens.

Comment: Since you are a new user, you might not know that it is expected that the answers here .will be useful for others while searching on the net. It is good to give a link where the questioner can get further information. (the reason I am not up-voting your correct answer)